# Как сделать ссылку на input?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Хочу сделать чтобы в зависимости от выбранного input отправлялось на нужный метод, Как можно сделать ссылку на этот инпут?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm($('input[name=simulators-tabs1]:checked').val(), new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "simulators" }))...
```

$('input[name=simulators-tabs1]:checked').val()-Какой код сделать, чтобы нормально работало?

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно в asp.net сделать ссылку на input?

Кратко: "Никак".

Я с подобной задачей не сталкивался, но примерно понимая механику чувствую, что вы идёте не в ту сторону и настоящее решение будет намного сложнее, чем просто получить значение выбранного input.

Место в котором вы пишете - это серверное место, оно [задаёт](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) первоначальное значение для action формы, там хоть кол на голове теши - но вы никакой input.val не подставите. Почитали описание функции в MSDN, видите хоть где-то намёк "тут можно вставить javascript-функцию"?

Если же вам нужна задача "выбор куда отправляется форма зависит, от выбранного input radio", то:

> Вам нужно вешать на каждый input функцию на onChanged которая будет
>   читать input.val и прописывать его на action формы.

---

PS И кроме того, лично у меня вызывает сомнения, что ваша изначальная задача вообще должна решаться именно в этой стороне, я считаю, что тут явно [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4900/213987).

Вероятно, если бы озвучили свою настоящую задачу, для которой вам понадобилось "action формы зависит от выбранного input" вам бы тут же сказали, что эту задачу принято решать иначе, а не идти кривыми окольными тропами.

Но если вам интересно как микроскопом забивать гвозди - тогда добавьте метку javascript и перефразируйте вопрос в терминах js, а не asp.net-mvc

Comment: У меня есть несколько табов переход между которыми отвечает input radio, на все хотел повесить одну форму, которая отвечала бы за отправку на сервер данных в табах есть элементы одни и те же элементы. Как можно сделать отправку формы на разные методы на сервер из одной формы?

Comment: @артемШеломенцев Вы не договариваете задачу. Если на разных табах одни и те же элементы - то это одна и та же форма, с одними и теми же элементами + некоторый input с именем selected_tab_id - и отправлять это нужно на один и тот же адрес, внутри которого будет анализироваться и selected_tab_id и набор элементов. Зачем, зачем писать пять ОДИНАКОВЫХ экшенов если можно написать один? Что такого в этой форме, этих элементов, что заставляет их отправлять на разные экшены? Пока вы не обосновали такую необходимость и не сказали, что за форма и что за элементы.

Comment: на табах не вся информация одинаковая, в каждом табе добавляется ещё ифна своя. Для этого и делается несколько методов, куда будух приходить.

Comment: @артемШеломенцев Тогда это несколько табов с разными формами, которые отправляются на жёстко фиксированные url. А переключение табов вызывает javascript, который копирует общие поля (они могут быть как в hidden'ах вне табов или визуально показаны вне табов) в конкретную форму (например, в hidden'ы). Это эквивалентно вашей задаче с "динамический action формы"? Просто менять адрес формы - это, ну как id'шники менять в базе или как "вам, товарищ милиционер, в бане - и без кобуры". Не делают так без особо острой небходимости и это как раз такой случай, когда не стоит.

Comment: @A K, Да. Я хотел бы еще раз убедиться, что мы поняли друг друга. Нет возможности в @using... использовать динамические формы?

Comment: @артемШеломенцев Верно: Ajax.BeginForm - никакой.

Comment: а в обычной форме??

Comment: @chilo5432 [Тоже нету](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd492719(v=vs.100)).